# Cannot bind value to attribute in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, binding, using-directives

This works:

```
<p class="form-control-static">{{ctrl.StatusId}}</p>
<div content-selects ng-model="Statuses" selection="2"></div>
```

This doesn't

```
<p class="form-control-static">{{ctrl.StatusId}}</p>
<div content-selects ng-model="Statuses" selection="ctrl.StatusId"></div>
```

In case one, `{{ctrl.StatusId}}` shows 2 and my directive works perfectly.
In case two, `{{ctrl.StatusId}}` also shows 2 and my directive doesn't work.

```
function contentSelects(){
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            templateUrl: '/app/Directives/contentSelects.tpl.html',
            replace:true,
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                selection: '='
            },
            controller:function($scope){

            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

               scope.selectedModel = scope.ngModel[scope.selection];
                console.log(scope.selectedModel);
                scope.isChanged = function () {
                    //console.log("changed");
                }

            }
        };
```

If I use curly brackets it breaks selection="{{ctrl.StatusId}}". What should I give this attribute so that it recognises the value that's passed?

Comment: `selection="{{ctrl.StatusId}}"` should work

Comment: it doesn't I get an error...

Comment: why you use ng-model. try

`scope.$watch("selectedModel", function(){
   console.log(scope.selectedModel);
})`

Comment: Thanks @Sandeep but I don't want to clutter the scope with watchers, I'd rather find out why a simple binding doesnt work.

Comment: Any idea @JBNizet, @Jigs?